# Tweak the StackOverflow nofollow tag for user profiles

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, nofollow

I've been wondering why my Google Buzz wasn't linking up with Superuser and Serverfault. I got a pretty good suggestion at [webapps.stackoverflow.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/how-do-i-get-google-buzz-to-see-my-other-stack-overflow-accounts). In short the theory is the `"rel~=nofollow"` throws it off. I'm wondering if it is appropriate to require a reputation of 2000 before the *nofollow* tag is dropped from the profile?

Google could certainly fix this on their end, but it seems as a copied profile should just carry over the dofollow link so Google makes the XFN for Buzz. Is it possible to remove this instance of "nofollow" or to find a different way to establish non-spammer status other than reputation? I presume you're doing this to prevent spam, rather than as an incentive to get 2000 reputation points.

I plan on using the other sites in the trilogy but I doubt I'll make 2000 reputation anytime soon on them.

I think this is the message that StackExchange is trying to send:

> Please come join our community. But, if your friends want to *follow* you, they'll have to join our community too. Thanks -- spam prevention team.

Comment: So *you're* the reason we have the nofollow tag.

Comment: I'm kidding, but I disagree with your idea.

Comment: I just want to make it easier for my fan club to use Google Buzz.

Comment: I think 2000 is a bit high for this kinda thing. Why not make it something lower like 500 or 1000 rep instead

Comment: @Earlz I think the *real reason* is the establishment doesn't want the independent thinking users to organize behind my Google Buzz -- something they have no control over short of disabling it.

Comment: @Evan no, I'm pretty sure it's for spam protection. Believe it or not, the administrators are not out to get you or your "fan club".

Comment: I don't know why you think you have a fan club.

Comment: `"Google could fix it on their end but..."` *You're not that important.*

Answer (score 4):

Addressing only your question, the reason for this is most likely spam protection. I say that the team should be safe in making the reputation requirement for `followme` links on the profile a little lower. I would suggest either 500 or 1000 reputation.

Comment: Then people will complain and it will be lowered to 200... then 100... then 50...

Answer (score 2):

The last time I looked at this with Sam Hasler, I was assured that the `rel="me"` and `rel="nofollow"` could be combined with no issues.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569

> If you host user profiles and allow users to link to other profiles on the web, we encourage you to mark those links with the rel="me" microformat so that they can be made available through the Social Graph API. For example:
>
> `<a href="http://blog.example.com" rel="me">My blog</a>`
>
> However, because these links are user-generated and may sometimes point to untrusted pages, we recommend that these links be marked with nofollow. For example:
>
> `<a href="http://blog.example.com" rel="me nofollow">My blog</a>`
>
> With rel="me nofollow", Google will continue to treat the rel="nofollow" as expected for search purposes, such as not transferring PageRank. However, for the Social Graph API, we will count the rel="me" link even when included with a nofollow.

Comment: Yes, I know this is their problem -- [check out their own lab experiment that can test follow="me" links](http://socialgraph-resources.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/exploreapi.html). Try it anyone that has less than 3k exp (nofollow)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if some user has earned certain amount of reputation , it has by his verified engagement earned both the trust, and the right to have link to his site without nofollow. Earning 1000 or 2000 of credit to put a link to your site would be a highly inefficient way of spamming. It is correct to give a back a little bit by stackexchange to the people who put their effort and knowledge into these sites.

Make it a badge.